# From what time can this jewelry date?

Tags: 20th-century, identification

Last summer my little brother dug up this piece of jewelry with his metal detector in France (near Vichy). It's roughly 5 cm from top to bottom. It has no hallmarks.

[image]

From what time period could this piece date? It is made from pure silver, and was buried about 20 cm deep in the ground in the middle of a piece of forest. As far as I could find, it looks like a (Victorian?) pocket watch fob from the early twentieth century. Is it possible that this is indeed that old?

Comment: Does it have any hallmarks?

Comment: Could you add a banana for scale? (How big is it?)

Comment: @ConradTurner It has no hallmarks as far as I can see. The picture container almost as much as there is to see

Comment: @Schwern I'm sorry to say that I've ran out of bananas today. It's roughly 5 cm from top to bott as in the picture, chains included.

Comment: To me, it looks too large and chunky (i.e. lacks fine detail) to be jewelry. Possibly, it's ornamentation for; a piece of furniture, a domestic fitting (such as a decorative light fitting) or some luggage.

Comment: @KillingTime i don't know, those chains are pretty tiny. Pure silver also seems quite expensive to put on furniture. Besides, it is more unlikely that that got into a random place in the middle of a forest. It could be some sort of ornament for a small (hand)bag or something similar

Comment: What does the other side look like?

Comment: Exactly the same as this side...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are probably correct with your assessment of the purpose and age of the item.  It does appear to be a [Victorian era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victorian_era) watch [fob](https://www.britannica.com/art/watch-fob), worn on a chain to aid in retrieving the [pocket watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_watch).

A similar item in [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/listing/478130725/large-victorian-silver-enamel-tassel-fob?ref=market) shows the similarity in overall design and especially the tassel style.
[image]
where the item is described as

> Large Victorian Silver Enamel Tassel Fob Pendant

Searching those keywords on google images will bring up other similar items on places like eBay and  Pinterest, most mentioning Victorian as age (some saying style,however)but I have not seen anything identical.  You may be able to find more info either from a book on jewelry, a local jeweler, or look for watch collectors who may have more specific info.